# Adobe Illustrator guides not snapping to Bounding Box handles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, snapping, bounding-box

I can not seem to snap a guide to the handle of a bounding box. Is this not a functionality Illustrator has?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have smart guides on? And what snap settings do you have enabled. Alignment guides should do the same thing.

Comment: I did not see this comment. Thank you for the response. I do have smart guides on, as well as snap to point. I just remember the rulers snapping to bounding boxes? (been a couple years since i moved the design fingers)

Comment: Yes but what are your snap setting in the preferences

Answer (score 0):

My *personal experience* is that **nothing** "snaps" to the Bounding Box in Illustrator, unless Adobe has implemented something recently.

The Bounding Box isn't a "thing", an "object", an actual piece of artwork. So, with AI logic, you can't snap to something that isn't a guide or an object and the Bounding Box is neither.

If something *appears* to snap to the Bounding Box, it is because the limits of the selection are at the edge of the Bounding Box, not due to the presence of the Bounding Box itself (Area type is a good example of this).

Now, InDesign **does** snap to *frames* which are kind of different, in terms of the logic I suppose, but strikingly similar to AI's Bounding Box.